# Convert Bluetooth Headset to 3.5mm Stereo Out And Mic In (Duplex)

Tags: audio, bluetooth, hardware-rec, headphones, wireless-headset

I know stereo 3.5mm jack to Bluetooth dongles exist for Bluetooth headphones.
But what if this is for a Bluetooth headset with a Mic?
Are there Bluetooth dongles for line-in also?

For example, my laptop has line-out (stereo) and line in (mic) jacks.
I want to use a bluetooth headset with this.
I don't want to use a bluetooth adapter since I will need to change my sound devices in the control panel when switching between my 3.5mm with line-in mic headset and my cheap Bluetooth headset.

I want to simply plug the Bluetooth dongle into my line in and stereo line-out jacks and have this sound sent to my Bluetooth headset without having to always change my sound configuration (default sound devices) in Skype, Windows, Google Voice plugin, etc.

Comment: Looking for exactly the same. Any joy?

Answer (score 0):

10 years later, and something that sounds so simple is still so difficult.

What would almost work is to get two Bluetooth-to-3.5mm adapters, one for receiving a Bluetooth audio stream from the transmitting headset and feeding it into the computer via 3.5mm, and one for receiving audio from the computer via 3.5mm audio jack and sending it to the headset via Bluetooth.

Most of these Bluetooth-to-3.5mm devices have a switch to change between transmit mode vs receive mode, such that you could use two of the same model, one in transmit mode, one in receive mode.

Where this breaks down is that from the headset's perspective, this would require simultaneous pairing with *two* audio devices, splitting inbound audio from outbound audio, and I do not know of any Bluetooth headset with that capability.

So then the only remaining option that comes readily to mind is to use something like a cheap Raspberry Pi which is a full Linux computer that already has a 3.5mm audio jack and Bluetooth capability, and configure software to route bidirectionally (full duplex) between 3.5mm and BT.  Alas, on a quick web search just now, the "configure software" bit of it will probably involve getting into very technical stuff and writing some software.  It can be done, but if you're not a computer programmer, might be infeasible.