# Possible to use Bluetooth headset in Stereo mode with Mic at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, adapter, headset

I would like to ask if there's any dongle out there to achieve HQ sound and mic at the same time. My father just gave me a pair of pods a few days ago and I wanted to use it for calls on my PC. Now I realize I can't do that with HQ sound, only mono, but was wondering if there's some sort of jack-to-bt adapter or something like that so I can use both functions in HQ at the same time. For the time being, at least I got APTX sound hehe.

More info:

[Possible to use Bluetooth headset in Stereo mode with Mic?](https://superuser.com/questions/930251/possible-to-use-bluetooth-headset-in-stereo-mode-with-mic)

[Convert Bluetooth Headset to 3.5mm Stereo Out And Mic In (Duplex)](https://superuser.com/questions/527298/convert-bluetooth-headset-to-3-5mm-stereo-out-and-mic-in-duplex)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the best possible audio quality over Bluetooth while using a microphone, both your headset and adapter must support either Aptx-Low Latency or FastStream.

Bluetooth bandwidth (at time for writing) is limited to about 1.5 Mbits/s under average conditions. Amazon's music app recommends a steady internet connection of 1.5 to 2 Mbps for HD streaming and 5 to 10 Mbps for Ultra HD streaming. As you can see, quality sound easily exceeds Bluetooth's limitations, hence the development of the AptX codec*. Therefore, the extra burden of the microphone/voice channel will always reduce the sound quality over bluetooth.

*AptX achieves a higher effective bit-rate by transmitting only the difference between the current sample and the next one

Comment: I know about AptX LL and FastStream now, I just can't find headsets of BT dongles with that technology, or at least I can't find any info in the products typical description.

Thanks for the info!